# Are there any serious pitfalls to Outsystems Agile Platform?

Tags: outsystems

We are currently looking into the Agile Platform by Outsystems.

We have went through their courses and did all the examples but from experience these types of things only show part of the picture.

Are there any serious pitfalls that we may not be aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER: I work for OutSystems*

Every development tool/language/stack/... involves some tradeoffs at some point. Therefore, depending on what you're looking for, or particularly interested in, you may consider some aspect of a platform as an unforgivable pitfall where others might see it as a godsend blessing, or vice-versa. Thus, only by knowing what you really like and what you consider essential, may I try to guess what you'll miss and what you'll consider a pitfall.

Since we usually only notice the lack of something the first time we try to use it, I'd recommend trying to use the platform to hack something at your will without following the tutorials and the courses to the letter. If while creating something different you find anything you dislike, we'll be happy to hear it from you!

TL;DR: If you think the tutorials for a tool aren't showing you something, play with it a bit without following them.

Comment: you are right Miguel. I just want to know that does Outsystems provide option for exporting app's HTML/CSS source code for PhoneGap IDE or ready to use code export option for different IDEs (eg. XCode, VB, Android etc)?

Answer (score 35):

I used Outsytems for a while due to company's new direction.

So far I found out that Outsytems is quite good in assisting even the newest/dullest programmers with developing a clean and maintainable data layers as well as readable logic. Even creating workflow is a breeze if you keep it within OutSystem.

TLDR: even the 'most newbiest' programmer can create a decent application using Outsystems.

**User interface**

One hiccup I have encountered so far is when we want to create a rather complex user interface (javascript plugins etc) that looks very different from Intelliwrap template.

Just like in any IT sales talk, "It can be done!" - it can always be done - but expect a lot of trial and error. The behaviors of javascript, css and such can be unpredictable at times - especially if you try to override most of the interface portion of the Outsystems.

Note that there are not many tutorial / forum post that discuss user interface aspect of Outsystems throughly since it is indeed difficult and in most aspect quite annoying.

**Automated test**

Another aspect that bother me is that the difficulty of creating a test driven development environment. In most cases, automated testing environment is almost impossible to set up.

Yes there are plugins and such but expect no support or whatsoever to set it up. Nuno from Outsystems has kindly showed me how Outsystems use automated testing tools on their platform development. However, this portion is not for everyone as it is very difficult to set up. Be prepared to do manual testing when doing development using Outsystems (e.g. hire lots of interns)

In our case, the problem of setting up testing tool is amplified since we are not using inteliwarp and default Outsystems UI component.

Doing agile development without automated testing is a bit weird - similar to visiting McDonalds that does not offer fries.

**Talent shortage**

Another issue that you might encounter when dealing with Outsystems will be possible bottlenecks due to limited supply of people with required skills.

Outsystems staff will help you as much as they can but when it comes to some kind of exotic integration with other systems or doing your own hacking (e.g. UI/database/etc) be prepared to be on your own. Google or Stackoverflow will not be of much help. As per today, only fewer than 20 questions are tagged with 'Outsystems' in Stack Overflow. Forget to find sample in Github.

You can always go to their community site which is quite active. However, be prepared to be on your own when you want to do something more than just standard Outsystems application.

In some cases, expert developers might find using Outsystems studio is nothing short of *insulting* and does not contribute much to their personal career development (e.g. limited job opportunities, depreciating original skills).

No matter what, you will almost never be able to find developer who can jump into the team doing Outsystems project immediately without prior training. This problem will be amplified if you plan to do a lot of modification and custom development.

**Version control**

Outsystems platform is bundled with its own *code repository / version control* mechanism but do not expect something like SVN or GIT. To be fair it is good enough for most cases but merging. The merging action is done at the file/component level. Outsystems can only detect if the file/component has been changed. The merging mechanism is essentially overwriting the entire file. No such thing as line-by-line code comparison/insertion/deletion (there is no code anyway).

Reverting to the older version of your work can be quite troublesome imho.

**Documentation / knowledge sharing**

Depending on your company culture, documenting or sharing best practice / cookbook / step-by-step instruction might be a bit hard due to the need of capturing screenshots all the time.

**TLDR**
If you just want to create simple CRUD systems with standard UI, just like any enterprise application, Outsystems will do its job well - very well indeed. Just do not expect too much of bell and whistles and remember: any custom development and alteration to the default framework will cost you (or your developer) dearly.

Comment: What about the sign in process of the apk, Is it possible to upload the application to the playstore, If I developed using Outsystems

Comment: I never reach this stage of development @geethu

Comment: so wht?.........................

Comment: User interface
Automated test
Talent shortage
Version control

Comment: Excel is a good tool up to a certain point (10000's rows and things start to unravel)... when you need a real Database.
Similarly,
Outsystems fills a gap for simple, canned apps - but should not be used for complex systems or trying to do anything outside-the-lines.
You nailed these *pretty important* items as deficient in Ousystems and that is also my experience.
* User interface (can't really customize it easily)
* Automated test (poor 3rd party plugin)
* Talent shortage (non-existent)
* Version control (built for 1 developer only, *do not* try this with teams)

Answer (score 8):

I've been using it to put together a project, and I am extremely happy with it. It makes 90% of a project extremely easy; it takes the advantages of an ORM but integrates it beautifully into the development system, the lifecycle is great on a project. I like the deployment/versioning/rollback story. Anything that falls outside of its realm is very easy to handle in Visual Studio using the Integration Studio.

I've found a couple of minor bugs along the way, but I have to say that the support team has been EXTREMELY responsive to them, even though I am an unpaying, "Community Edition" member. The support in the forums, both from OutSystems and from the other users has been outstanding.

The ONLY hitch that I've found, is that it currently is no compatible with .NET 4 and Visual Studip 2008. I've been told that it is on the roadmap. If you have code that *must* use .NET 4 before they get that support in, you can easily wrap it in a WCF service and import that service directly in Service Studio. This is what I did, and it turned out to be a big benefit since the .NET 4 code was very resource intensive so I now have some scalability options.

Hope this helps!

J.Ja

Answer (score 7):

Totally Agreed
This product is a nightmare. I'm a external freelance consultant developing projects for various clients across Africa and US. Recently one of my client wanted me to develop custom product for his business in Durban. With just 2 days of testing the code I suggested my client that OUTSYSTEMS product would be worst possible solution for any business and there would be no scope for the future.

CONS
 1. Not User Friendly as they proclaim in OUTSYSTEMS.com
 2. Take Horrible amount of time to do simple Operations
 3. Very pathetic video tutorials and really irritates to hear the VO of explaining a simple operation
4. Confuses users to do simple operations
5. Compatibility Issues with versions.
6. Integration Issues with multiple third parties
7. Tons of bugs while using Integration studio as system freezes 
8. Cannot build Custom Templates and designs 
9. Cannot import simple layouts inside the system 
10. Would be nightmare for scalability and controlls

Comment: This is either really outdated information, or the writer didn't work in the platform

Answer (score 5):

I've been using the platform for > 2.5 years now and haven't found any serious shortcomings.

I've been implementing several projects (mostly data management and/or integration type applications) and have been very successful with the platform ...

Feel free to contact me if you have specific questions: http://www.linkedin.com/in/stefanmeier

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: What about merging conflicts?

Comment: OutSystems can deal with merging, and it's at least more simple than using the traditional V-SourceSafe, as per my experience using OutSystems over Visual Studio.

Comment: Really? What do you think of the version control compared to, say, git or svn?

Comment: the version control for outsystems are pathetic. there is no such thing as code compare, pull request and such.

Answer (score 2):

The worst AGILE product I have come across.
This product is surely not for those who want some kind of intelligence. The product is more a gimmick and I presume this is only good to develop a website.

If you are a serious developer and developing a custom build solutions like supply chain or ERP based application, seriously consider using any opensource or even an excel sheet, or better start using old book keeping style and it's worth it. You will get stressed with the product and the pricing